Ac drain pipe leaking
AC drain is in a horrible position - it's leaking on my concrete. will it cause damage?
I live in hot area. Any ideas to fix?
I did a bandage job. AC guy wanted to get a pump from furnace through attic for a better looking but gonna cost $4500.


A condensate pump to a plastic tube would cost you maybe a hundred bucks if you did it yourself.  Couple hundred more to use PVC pipe put in by someone else.

If the drain ts from the condenser of the AC it looks like whoever's put it in did a bad job on your stucco. Yes extend the PVC pipe, but use pvc glue, water will otherwise leak at the joints. If the pipe is from a direct vent gas furnace you will need special glue. The condensate from the burner is very acidic.

Those drainline are almost always 3/4" pvc.  A few fittings and length of pipe will be less than $20.
They can be press fit together.  (no glue because no pressure)
Then you can direct the water to wherever you want it to go.
